# How to create a priority service thread pool in IBM WAS 8.5

Tags: websphere

I have deployed 3 war files in IBM WAS 8.5 (SupposeA.war ,B.war and C.war) ,I want A.war, B.war to be deployed first then C deployment should start.

Is there any way to do it.

This is required as my C.war is dependent on A.war and B.war.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are referring to the order of application start ("deploy" in WebSphere parlance is often used to refer to installation of an application, but that does not appear to be the issue here), then you would want to modify the applications' starting weights, as documented here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.iseries.doc/ae/trun_app_startup.html

If these WARs are all part of the same EAR, the WARs' starting weights can be set separately within the EAR in the "Manage Modules" panel within the application configuration in the administrative console.

Comment: All are different EARs , in same node but different ports. Instead doing some changes at server level,can we bind any dependencies on the ear/war so that we can fix something at code level.

Comment: The starting weight ordering is an application setting after deployment, not something you could set within the application. I don't have a great idea for how to simulate that behavior in code other than perhaps having some sort of logic in the "later" apps that checks for the availability of the resources from the "earlier" apps and retries until they're ready (there might be a better way, but I'm not sure).